# Querying gatsby graphql build server

Tags: gatsby

Are there any built-in or third party tools for querying the gatsby graphql server?
I mean actual queries, and not the 'pageQuery', 'staticQuery' or 'useStaticQuery' functionality?

My end goal being - I'd like to retrieve page information during the onRenderBody event based on the page pathname.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you need to use the `createPages` API and then pass whatever info you need that you'd get from a query into `context` so that it will be accessible inside of your `template`/`component` as a prop - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#usage

Comment: @goto1 Making a static ssr header via the onRenderBody event. I don't see any relation between context and the onRenderBody function - unless there's some plugin that passes context to onRenderBody.